# Adding new eventHandler in RadioButton CheckedChanges in dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, event-handling

I'm trying to add another `eventHandler` to `RadioButton`. This is the sample code (which is working):

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton RB1 = new RadioButton();
    RB1.ID = "1";
    RB1.GroupName = "bla";
    RB1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckedChanged);
    RadioButton RB2 = new RadioButton();
    RB2.ID = "2";
    RB2.GroupName = "bla";
    RB2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckedChanged);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(RB1);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(RB2);

}
protected void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = ((RadioButton)sender).ID;
}
```

In my project I have dynamic creating of `RadioButtons` (the number of rows I get from database). The same adding `eventHandler` does not work, but if I write

```
MyRadioButton.Load += new EventHandler(Another_method);
```

The `Another_method` will start, but in

```
MyRadioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Main_method);
```

the `Main_method` will not start if I choose one of the `RadioButtons`.
What is wrong?

---

@KevinP
This is my code:

```
    Table tb1 = new Table();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb1);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    //adding the first row with title"
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    for (int i = 0; i < ((ArrayList)(result[0])).Count; i++)
    {
        tc = new TableCell();
        Label example = new Label();
        example.Text = ((columnsResultFromSqlClients)(i)).ToString();
        tc.Controls.Add(example);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    }
    tb1.Rows.Add(tr);
    //filling the table
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    {
        tr = new TableRow();
        tc = new TableCell();
        //adding radio button
        RadioButton RB = new RadioButton();
        RB.Attributes.Add("value", ((ArrayList)(result[i]))[0].ToString());
        RB.GroupName = "for_selecting";
        RB.ID = ((ArrayList)(result[i]))[0].ToString();
        RB.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RB_CheckedChanged2);
        //RB.AutoPostBack = true;

        RB.Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "True");
        tc.Controls.Add(RB);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        //adding content
        for (int j = 0; j < ((ArrayList)(result[i])).Count; j++)
        {
            tc = new TableCell();
            Label example = new Label();
            example.Text = ((ArrayList)(result[i]))[j].ToString();
            tc.Controls.Add(example);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        }
        tb1.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
```

If I use `RB.AutoPostBack = true;`, I have no time to press the button to submit my choice, cause the page will reload when i click the one of the Radio Buttons.
Also the `RB_CheckedChanged2` code:

```
protected void RB_CheckedChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton tempRB = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (tempRB.Checked)
    {
        selected_id = tempRB.ID;
    }
}
```

The `select_id` is a `static int` varible with standart value = "-1".

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, with dynamic controls in ASP.Net, you need to "rewire" their events on a postback.  Remember that on a postback, dynamic controls are no longer there.  You have to recreate them.